# Load MySQL data dynamically by unique id into Bootstrap modal -CodeIgniter

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, bootstrap-modal

Having successfully eliminated the issue from a previous question I posed in [add limit to data passed to bootstrap modal with foreach() in codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38215952/add-limit-to-data-passed-to-bootstrap-modal-with-foreach-in-codeigniter/38574194#38574194), I now find myself with the residue of that issue. As succinctly posited by @webcrazymaniac;

**`The idea is to have a unique modal window, with it's unique id for each article, uniquely called with the corresponding button`**

According to the solution listed in [Send parameter to Bootstrap modal window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24323895/send-parameter-to-bootstrap-modal-window), I should be able to have my desired effect as stated above - adapted as;

**On page Modal**

```
    <!-- alert view -->
<div class='modal fade' id='myModal' role='dialog'>
<div class='modal-dialog'>
  <!-- Modal content-->

  <div class='modal-content' id='#myModal<?php echo $a->art_id;?>'>   
    <div class='modal-header'>
      <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='modal' aria-hidden='true'>&times;</button>
      <h2 class='modal-title'>Title:&nbsp;<?php echo $a->title;?></h2>
    </div>
    <div class='modal-body'>
      <h3>Category:&nbsp;<?php echo $a->cat_name;?></h3>
      <h3>Date:&nbsp;<?php echo $a->public_date;?></h3>
      <h3>Content:&nbsp;<?php echo $a->description;?></h3>
    </div>      
    <div class='modal-footer'>
      <button type='button' class='btn btn-default' data-dismiss='modal'>Close</button>
    </div>      
  </div>

</div>
```

**jQuery Script**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$( document ).ready(function() {       
$('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) { //Modal Event
var id = $(e.relatedTarget).data('id'); //Fetch id from modal trigger button
$.ajax({
  type : 'POST',
   url : 'query.php', //Here you will fetch records 
   data :  'post_id='+ id, //Pass $id
   success : function(data){
     $('.form-data').html(data);//Show fetched data from database
     }
   });
  });
 });
</script>
```

**Modal Trigger Button**

```
 echo "<a href='#myModal/".$a->art_id."' class='btn btn-success btn-sm' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModal' data-id='".$a->art_id."'>View</a> &nbsp;".
```

**query.php**

```
<?php
//Include database connection here
$dsn = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=articles;charset=utf8';
$user ='';
$pass ='';
$options = array(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC, PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION, PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);      
try {
$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $options);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
file_put_contents('PDOErrors.txt', $e->getMessage(), FILE_APPEND);
}

if($_POST['art_id']) {
    $id = $_POST['art_id'];
    $category = $_POST['cat_name'];
    $public_date = $_POST['public_date'];
    $description = $_POST['description'];


 // Run the Query
$sql = "SELECT `art_id`, `cat_name`, `public_date`, `description` FROM `articles` WHERE `art_id`='?'";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);        
// Fetch Records
$stmt->execute();
}
?>
```

It all works to call the modal, but this attempt only nets me the 5th result on-page for all (green) buttons clicked. As (maybe) an important note, I'm having trouble with `data-id='#myModal<?php echo $a->art_id;?>` fitting into the modal trigger button as it destroys the popup of the modal. I know I have to maybe pull a destruction mode in order to change to another ID like so;

```
    $('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
      $(this).removeData('bs.modal');
 });
```

Now, mind you, I'm not especially conversant in `jQuery`, so what I've come up with is based on a solid few hours of reading and experimentation. Having pored over numerous examples, I'm still at a loss as to **exactly** how to make this all work. I'm really stuck as I'm getting the same result (off by a factor of either the display of the first or fifth result for clicking green buttons) whether I'm trying this straight `PHP` or `jQuery`.  It seems like every question that I've read in this category of question gets me to the current dilemma I'm in where if I use the `PHP` version solution, I'm returned the 1st page result for every view button on the page. `jQuery` solution returns the fifth page result for each view button. **This is strange indeed...**  Not even changing out the jQuery for simplified `js` like this;

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//jQuery Library Comes First
//Bootstrap Library
($ 'a[data-toggle=modal]').click ->
target = ($ @).attr('data-target')
url = ($ @).attr('href')
($ target).load(url)
```

I was pulling for that snippet to rescue me, but, no. Neither did this one;

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 //jQuery Library Comes First
 //Bootstrap Library
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {

    var $modal = $(this),
    modal_title = $(this).data('modal-title'),
    modal_params = $(this).data('modal-params');

    if(typeof modal_title !== typeof undefined && modal_title !== false) {
        title = modal_title;
    }
    else{
        title = 'Title';
        }

    $.ajax({
        cache: false,
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'query.php',
        data: modal_params,
        success: function(data) {
            $modal.find('.modal-title').html(title);
            $modal.find('.modal-body').html(data);
         }
      });
    });

  });
</script>
//crabbed from 
//https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35702374/bootstrap-modal-with-individual-attributes
```

But, as par for the course, **no love...** There's either `Human Error` to blame, or I'm just missing something plainly hiding in full view. Having read more than 200-plus questions today, I'm having problems re-reading this for formatting, etc. (lol!). Learned tons, but still stuck.

**UPDATE**

In the time since I've looked at what @progrAmmar suggested, I went back to try and refine my approach. The key issue is how to make the `jQuery` reload process;

```
$('body').on('hidden.bs.modal', '.modal', function () {
    $(this).removeData('bs.modal');
```

clear out the modal so that upon click of another button, the corresponding table row content flows in like water. I'm having problems figuring out what sequencing is correct for the `jQuery` - as it stands now;

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    //jQuery Library Comes First
    //Bootstrap Library
     $(document).ready(function() {
    // Fill modal with content from link href
    $('.myModal').on('click', function(e) {
        var link = $(this).data('href');
    $('#myModal').modal('show');
    $('#myModal .modal-body').load(link );

    $('body').on('hidden.bs.modal', '.modal', function () {
     $(this).removeData('bs.modal');

    });
  })
</script>
```

Which results in the view below:

[image: Current result of attempted jQuery solution]

If you look on the bottom-left of the image you'll see the corresponding id value is `3`, but the open modal is pulling content from id value `5`. I'm still having the process of calling the modal and displaying table row go smoothly, but the modal reload process is bent. Suggestions? I'm out of ideas at this point.

**@progrAmmar**, I went back to your proffered suggestion, but these are the following things preventing me from fully adapting;

**article/index (controller/index function)**

```
public function index()
{
    $modal = $this->article_model->modal($art_id=NULL);
    $category = $this->category_model->listAll();
    $article =$this->article_model->index($this->limit);
    $total_rows=$this->article_model->count();

    $config['total_rows']=$total_rows;
    $config['per_page']=$this->limit;
    $config['uri_segment']=3;
    $config['base_url']=site_url('article/index');

    $this->pagination->initialize($config);
    $page_link =$this->pagination->create_links();
    $this->load->view('admin/article',compact('article', 'page_link', 'category', 'modal'));

}
```

**article_model.php**

```
public function modal($art_id)
    {
      $data = array();
      $this->db->select('art_id', 'cat_name', 'public_date', 'description');
      $this->db->from('tbl_article');
      $query = $this->db->get();
       if($query->num_rows() > 0)
       {
         $results = $query->result();
       }
      return $results;

    }
```

Still trying to figure out where the needle is here. Thanks again for your suggestions @progrAmmar.

**UPDATE ANNOYANCES**

Back to purely `PHP` as `jQuery` wasn't doing anything different for me - even after playing around with @progrAmmar's code. Now I'm left back at ground zero and having read for another two hours (mainly @ the jQuery forum). :sigh:

**ALMOST THERE....**

After consulting the BS 3.3.5 docs, I **know** my answer is in the `Varying modal content based on trigger button` section. Tried to extrapolate this;

```
//Modal window trigger button  
echo "<a href='".base_url()."article/$a->art_id' class='btn btn-success btn-sm' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModal' data-id='".$a->art_id."'>View</a> &nbsp;".  

//jQuery code  
 $('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
 var button = $(event.relatedTarget) // Button that triggered the modal
 var id = button.data('id') // Extract info from data-* attributes
 var href = button.data('href') // Extract info from data-* attributes
 var target = button.data('target') // Extract info from data-* attributes
 // If necessary, you could initiate an AJAX request here (and then do the updating in a callback).
// Update the modal's content. We'll use jQuery here, but you could use a data binding library or other methods instead.
var modal = $(this)
modal.find('.modal-title').text('Title:')
modal.find('.modal-body').val('Category:')
modal.find('.modal-body').val('Date:')
modal.find('.modal-body').val('Content:')
$('#myModal > div.modal-body).empty();
})
```

I'm pretty sure I'm doing it wrong as I just can't get my head around any attempted extrapolations - been poring over other solution examples on SO, but am still working out approaches to the above coding. Research in motion...

**Extrapolating Code Proffered By @progrAmmar;**

```
Controller Article(.php)
------------------------

    public function index()
{
       $data['modal'] = $this->article_model->modal($art_id); // Gets all the data 
       $this->load->view('('admin/article',compact('article', 'page_link', 'category', 'modal') $data);
    }  

    View article(.php)
    ------------------

    <div class='modal fade' id='myModal' role='dialog'>
      <div class='modal-dialog'>
         <!-- Modal content-->

    <div class='modal-content' id='myModal'>      
       <div class='modal-header'>
         <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='modal' aria-hidden='true'>&times;</button>
         <h2 class='modal-title'>Title:&nbsp;<?php echo $a->title;?></h2>
    </div>

    <div class="modal-body">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col col-md-12">
          <h3>Category:&nbsp;<?php echo $a->cat_name;?></h3>
      <h3>Date:&nbsp;<?php echo $a->public_date;?></h3>
          <h3>Content:&nbsp;<?php echo $a->description;?></h3>
          <input type="hidden" id="hidId" value="<?php echo $a->art_id;?>" />
       </div>
    </div>
    </div>
     <div class='modal-footer'>
      <button type='button' class='btn btn-default' data-dismiss='modal'>Close</button>
    </div>  

//Finally call the html via JavaScript
 $.get(window.base_url + 'index.php/article/'+ id, function (data) {
      $('#myModal' > div.modal-body).empty();
      $('#myModal').html('data');
      $('#myModal').modal('show');
 }
```

Did a little juggling to fit in this attempt, but there's no change as the fifth page result is never bumped out by another content ID as shown below;

[image: Attempting solution offered by @progrAmmar]

Still stuck in the same position before...round and round we go ミ●﹏☉ミ

Of the section I'm interested in within the docs;

```
  $('#exampleModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
  var button = $(event.relatedTarget) // Button that triggered the modal
  var recipient = button.data('whatever') // Extract info from data-* attributes
  // If necessary, you could initiate an AJAX request here (and then do the updating in a callback).
 // Update the modal's content. We'll use jQuery here, but you could use a data binding library or other methods instead.
 var modal = $(this)
 modal.find('.modal-title').text('New message to ' + recipient)
 modal.find('.modal-body input').val(recipient)
})
```

my primary issue is;
HOW do I extrapolate `Update the modal's content`? 
**THIS** is essentially the core of my impedance and not located by an intensive search of the BS docs. If I could sync up some kind of way to force-reload the content within the modal, I have my answer. In fact the closest I've found to any example of how to (maybe) approach this was a post here (sorry forgot which one) detailing how to reload an image within a modal by targeting the `src` element;

```
//And then you just change the src attribute of the picture element from your function.
var picture = button.data('picture')    
$('#picture').attr('src',picture);
```

**THAT'S IT!* (theoretically)...Between the above example and the `Varying modal content based on trigger button` example, I'm on my way to losing it. I can't believe I can't just make the logical connection required to fire off the force-reload. I just don't see it, and every example I've used thus far keeps me in the same place.**

Having gone through fifty-plus JQuery code examples, not one of them did squat as far as activating any functionality, so I'm off attempting to use it as any sort of solution. **NONE** of the answers under this topic worked (even a little). This is the 1st time in my career where I've been completely stumped with nowhere to turn.

Here are the things I've tried:

### Situation 1

Initially dealing with an `HTML` table `<table class="table table-condensed">` listing out the `articles` db elements of `'art_id', 'title', 'cat_name', 'public_date', 'image'`, the table elements are scooped from the db with `foreach ($article->result() as $a){`.

The table ends with the `activity` buttons, the 1st of which is the BS modal trigger (unable to change table being echoed out in `PHP` - just mucks it all up);

```
echo "<a href='".base_url()."article/#myModal/$a->art_id' button class='btn btn-success btn-sm' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModal' data-id='".$a->art_id."'>View</a> &nbsp;".
```

### **Situation 2**

The modal data-toggle (as posted above) is the trigger for the modal to popup and is located on page bottom;

```
<!-- alert view -->
<div id="myModal<?php echo $a->art_id" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
  <!-- Modal content-->
  <?php
  $i=0;
  foreach ($article->result() as $a){    
  ?>
  <div id="#myModal<?php echo $a->art_id ?>" class="modal-content">  
      <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
      <h2 class='modal-title'>Title:&nbsp;<?php echo $a->title;?></h2>
    </div>
    <div class='modal-body'>
      <h3>Category:&nbsp;<?php echo $a->cat_name;?></h3>
      <h3>Date:&nbsp;<?php echo $a->public_date;?></h3>
      <h3>Content:&nbsp;<?php echo $a->description;?></h3>
    </div>      
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    </div>      
  </div>
  <?php
     if(!$i=0) break;
  $i++;
  }
  ?>
</div>
```

If the modal `foreach` isn't both included and augmented like so;

```
    <?php
  if(!$i=0) {
    break;
  } else {
  $i++;  
  }}
  ?>
```

then the modal pulls all of the `$a->art_id` elements into view simultaneously like so;

[image: Consequences of missing code piece]

And, even with the necessary `jQuery` at the bottom (after the modal);

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.myModal').click(function(event){
      var $link = $(this);
      new BootstrapDialog({
    title   :   'Title : ' + $link.attr('href'),
    content :   $('<div>Loading...</div>').load($link.attr('href')),
    buttons :   [{
        label   :   'Close',
        onclick :   function(dialog){
            dialog.close();
        }
    }, {
        label   :   'View',
        cssClass:   'btn-primary',
        onclick :   function(dialog){
            alert('The content of the dialog is: ' + dialog.getBody().html());
            dialog.close();
        }
    }]
}).open();

event.preventDefault();
   });
  });
 });
 </script>  
//crabbed from - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14045515/how-can-i-reuse-one-bootstrap-modal-div/14059187#14059187
```

### **Situation 3**

**NOTHING WORKS...**. The jQuery is not destroying and reloading the modal, so I'm only getting that 1st on-page result from the 1st button on the page (completely correct content and ID). The most frustrating thing is if I hover over each button, the correct content ID is returned. I think it's safe to say that it's not any problem with the code - I have to investigate **WHY** that specific code isn't working on-page. Confusing because I'm using `jQuery` already;

```
    <script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>asset/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>asset/js/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
```

putting these two lines just above the modal and `jQuery` at the bottom of the page. It looks as if there is a conflict somewhere preventing the `jQuery`-driven script from firing. The only conflict I can maybe even see is that with the `CKEditor` that loads just above the `jQuery`.

Even with switching to another code block;

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.myModal').click(function(){
$(this).find('.inner').clone().appendTo('#myModal .modal-content');
$('#myModal .modal-title .modal-body .control-group.hide').show();
$('#myModal').modal();
});

 $('#myModal').on('hidden', function(){
 $('#myModal .inner').remove();
});
});
</script>//forgotten SO crabbing
```

I keep getting the same results. Since throwing in the towel, I've come upon several SO solutions which suggest the scenario I want, but I can never physically fulfill them and it making me angrier than a rattlesnake in a Texans' boot. Not only were these questions completely similar to mine, but they (almost) all got upvoted @ +1 or better, and the selected solutions did nothing to extract me from my bottleneck.

This is an issue that I'd like to see cleared up as I know there's a solution, and from the numerous `Fiddle`s and `Plunker`s, they're all similar in nature with slight variations that I haven't been able to employ.

Comment: Thanks for the downvote - sorry if it seems I didn't make my point for you - whoever you are. After reading 200-plus questions, maybe I didn't make my case as uniquely (sic) as possible - thanks for suggesting an answer also...

Comment: Psychotic...searching for the information on how to simply reload the content of a bootstrap modal in a dynamic fashion is proving to be the proverbial needle. Every SO question regarding this has, incomprehensibly, left me void of an issue resolution as well a creeping insanity - **why is it I can't find this info????**

Comment: So desperate, I rewrote code to accommodate @progrAmmar example - still no &%#*@^! joy. **This is gonna be a long week...**

Comment: This is a valiant and impressive effort, but the resulting post is probably way too long for most readers. It's worth trimming down a question to its core parts, rather than amending it too much in diary-fashion. Of course if you continue to get stuck, it may be worth asking for help using pair-programming, e.g. using AirPair or similar.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest (and probably the easiest) way to call a MODAL for data is to call the HTML from the server.

Create a separate view for your model. 
Call the data into it, load the model from the controller.

Here's how I am calling my Modal with codeigniter

**Controller**

```
public function EditData($id)
{
    $data['entity'] = $this->Home_model->getData($id); // Gets all the data
    $this->load->view('Home/modal_data', $data);
}
```

**views/Home/modal_data.php**

```
<div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
    <h4 class="modal-title">Edit <?= $entity['name'] ?></h4>
</div>

<div class="modal-body">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col col-md-12">
            <label>Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="txtName" class="form-control" value="<?= $entity['name'] ?>" />
            <input type="hidden" id="hidId" value="<?= $entity['id'] ?>" />
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success has-spinner" id="btnSave">
        <span class="spinner"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-spin glyphicon-refresh"></i></span>Save
    </button>
</div>
```

Make sure you have a modal div on your page to call the html into.

**views/Home/index.php**

```
<html>
.
.
.
    <body>
        <div id="home_modal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
              <div class="modal-dialog">
                  <div class="modal-content" id="home_modal_cont">
                  </div>
               </div>
         </div>
    </body
</html>
```

Finally call the html via JavaScript

```
$.get(window.base_url + 'index.php/home/EditData/'+ id, function (data) {
        $('#home_modal_cont').empty();
        $('#home_modal_cont').html(data);
        $('#home_modal').modal('show');
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your effort @progAmmar, but I'm having a hard time reconciling your solution to my current code flow. I'm not having **any** problems **calling** my modal - just having the modal content refresh to reflect the data coming from its' particular table row. And, the structure of the application disallows my use of this approach, sorry. I'm posting an update of where I'm at in a few minutes.

Comment: I don't see your `WHERE` query in your `article_model`. Also, what you need to do is destroy your modal. If you look closely in my javascript what I am doing `$(...).empty()` it basically erases all html from my Modal and then I replace the inner html with the new html provided by the server based on the data

Comment: Where you are doing removeData you may try `$('#myModal > div.modal-body).empty();`

Comment: Thanks for that observation, @progrAmmar - the **1st** thing I tried was the move to destroy and reload the modal - if I can get to that plateau, it's smooth sailing from there. Before your answer, I spent a few hours chasing down that info to no avail.

Comment: could you **please** provide some pseudo-code in this general direction? ATM I'm reading the BS 3.3.5 docs section on `Varying modal content based on trigger button` - my answer is **right there**, but I'm having problems as I'm very weak on jQuery (this will change...) and I'm attempting to contextualize it to my specific issue.

Comment: OK - I see what you mean in the `$get` part - am in process of dissection now - I wasn't getting how you were structuring your modal call.

Comment: The `$.get` gives me the HTML structured by the server I just display that in the modal